# JPA Entity with id from referencing class

Tags: jpa

Say I have a class ClassA and a class ClassB. ClassA maintains a reference to a List with a OneToManny dependency, and has an id set by the application. ClassB hasn't a reference to ClassA. Dependency is unidirectional.

Since each JPA Entity requires an Id, I have to specify an Id for ClassB, but id for ClassB is composed from ClassA's Id and ClassB's Id. Is there a way to model this without adding a reference from ClassB to ClassA (I know I can use @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn in this case)?

EDIT

I'm trying to use `@Embeddable` and `@ElementCollection` but I'm getting an `AnnotationException: List/array has to be annotated with an @OrderColumn (or @IndexColumn): my.package.PoiDetails.tips`.

Here is the complete code (take `PoiDetails` as `ClassA` and `Comment` as `ClassB`). As you can suppose a `Comment` primary key is a combination of `User`'s id, `Comment`'s timestamp, and `Poi`'s id.

ClassA:

```
@Entity
public class PoiDetails implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns(value = { 
        @JoinColumn(name="poiId", referencedColumnName="id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="categoryId"),
        @JoinColumn(name="providerId", referencedColumnName="providerId")})
private Poi poi;

@Transient
private User[] peopleHere;


@ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
        name="tips"
  )  
private Comment[] tips;

@ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
        name="queries"
  )
private Comment[] queries;

}
```

ClassB:

```
@Embeddable
public class Comment implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String text;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userId")
private User user;
private long timestamp;

public Comment(String text, User user, long timestamp) {
    super();
    this.text = text;
    this.user = user;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
public Comment(){}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

Poi:

```
@Entity
public class Poi implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private long id;
@Id
private long categoryId;
@Id
private long providerId;

private String title;

private String description;

private String positionLat;

private String positionLong;

private String positionAlt;

public Poi(){}

public Poi(long id, String title, String description, String positionLat, String positionLong, String positionAlt) {
    this(id, -1, title, description, positionLat, positionLong, positionAlt);
}

public Poi(long id, long categoryId, String title, String description, String positionLat, String positionLong, String positionAlt) {
    this.id = id;
    this.categoryId=categoryId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.positionLat = positionLat;
    this.positionLong = positionLong;
    this.positionAlt = positionAlt;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getPositionLat() {
    return positionLat;
}
public void setPositionLat(String positionLat) {
    this.positionLat = positionLat;
}
public String getPositionLong() {
    return positionLong;
}
public void setPositionLong(String positionLong) {
    this.positionLong = positionLong;
}
public String getPositionAlt() {
    return positionAlt;
}
public void setPositionAlt(String positionAlt) {
    this.positionAlt = positionAlt;
}

public long getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(long categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public long getProviderId() {
    return providerId;
}

public void setProviderId(long providerId) {
    this.providerId = providerId;
}
}
```

And User:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String id;
private String nickname;
private String thumbnailUrl;

public User(){}

public User(String userId, String nickname){
    this(userId, nickname, null);
}

public User(String id, String nickname, String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.id=id;
    this.nickname=nickname;
    this.thumbnailUrl=thumbnailUrl;
}

public User(String userId) {
    this.id=userId;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String userId) {
    this.id = userId;
}

public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname=nickname;
}

public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnail;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a ManyToOne is the best solution.

You could also add a Basic for the foreign key field, but this is not a good design.

Another alternative is to map ClassB as an Embeddable and use and ElementCollection mapping,

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: I'm trying to use Embeddable and ElementCollection but I'm getting in troubles. See edits.